# keep answered questions and delete others in a grouped by select SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `questions` table with these fields :

```
question_id  
text  
answer
```

There is many question that have exactly same text. But some of them are not answered and their's `answer` is null.

I want to select questions that have same text then keep one of them that have answered (for example is not null) and delete others.

For that I successfully wrote this SQL :

```
SELECT
  group_concat(question_id),
  text,
  count(question_id) AS count
FROM questions
GROUP BY text
HAVING count > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This is a result :

[image]

But I do not know how can I do what I said above.

I'm using mysql.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: do you have to delete them from the table? what do you want to do if there are no questions answered for a given text?

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to extract max(answer) for each distinct text. So,perform

```
select text,max(answer) as Maxanswer FROM questions group by text
```

This will give you the max(answer) for each text group.

Next do an inner join with the question table to retrieve the question_id of each distinct text which has the max(answer).

```
Select question_id from questions q1
inner join (select text,max(answer) as Maxanswer FROM questions group by text)dt
on dt.maxanswer=q1.answer and dt.text=q1.text
```

You need to save only the rows which have the text with max(answer).So, do a left join of the above questions table with the above select.(question table to left).View the results with Select command first before the delete

```
Select *
from questions q
left join
(Select question_id from questions q1
inner join (select text,max(answer) as Maxanswer FROM questions group by text)dt
on dt.maxanswer=q1.answer and dt.text=q1.text)dt1
on q.question_id =dt1.question_id 
where dt1.question_id  is null
```

From above select,the values of dt1 against q table are not null only for question_ids with text of max(answer).Then modify the select to delete as below

```
delete q
from questions q
left join
(Select question_id from questions q1
inner join (select text,max(answer) as Maxanswer FROM questions group by text)dt
on dt.maxanswer=q1.answer and dt.text=q1.text)dt1
on q.question_id =dt1.question_id 
where dt1.question_id  is null
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply (e.g. which indexes should be present).

Comment: It got me this error : `Unknown column 'dt1.text' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @A.B.Developer It should be dt.text. Corrected the code and added some explanation.

Comment: @Kapil, I tried your solution, but beacause my table has many records about 30,000, your sql takes up a lot of time sot that is running while I'm writing this comment